# Creare GoogleCredential in Delegate domain-wide authority using json file

Tags: java, google-oauth

with the following code i create a GoogleCredential and it works.

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(transport).setJsonFactory(jsonFactory).setServiceAccountId(serviceAccountUserEmail).setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("blabla04e85817bf4f.p12")).setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY)).setServiceAccountUser("xxx").build();
```

It's possibile to use a .json file instead of a .p12 file to create a GoogleCredential object?

I know i can create an object in this manner:

```
GoogleCredential.fromStream(resourceAsStream)
```

but with this method i cannot set a ServiceAccountUser via `.setServiceAccountUser("....)`

Thanks